# How to call default action and send parameter without action name

Tags: .net-core, routes

```
public class bController : Controller
{
   
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have controller like this. 
When I want to call index action I need the go to url 
http://localhost/b/index/id .
But ı want to like this 
http://localhost/b/id
 how can i set this action default and call like this. Give me idea pls 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wonder how to do this this is the answer.

```
  public class bController : Controller
  {
    [Route("b/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
  }
```